# Random failure on Hudson for Maven builds

Tags: java, maven, hudson, hudson-plugins

Since migrating to Maven, a lot of Java project builds on Hudson randomly fail with the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Process did not initiate connection and is still alive; killing it 
[ERROR] Failure: hudson.AbortException: Process failed to connect; exit code: 143 
ERROR: Process failed to connect; exit code: 143
```

The build queue is not full. The next build usually works just fine. Any clues on what is happening?

I'm using Hudson version 3.2.1 with Hudson Maven3 Plug-in version 3.0.4

Full log (edited for simplicity/security):

```
Started by user anonymous
Building on master
Updating {svn path} revision: {date} depth:infinity ignoreExternals: false
At revision {number}
no change for {svn path} since the previous build
[INFO] Using bundled Maven 3 installation
[INFO] Checking Maven 3 installation environment
[workspace] $ {maven home}/mvn --help
[INFO] Checking Maven 3 installation version
[INFO] Detected Maven 3 installation version: 3.1.1
[workspace] $ {maven home}/mvn clean package -V -B -Dmaven.ext.class.path={classpath} -Dhudson.eventspy.port=54304 -f pom.xml
[DEBUG] Waiting for connection on port: 54304
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 12:22:22-0300)
Maven home: {maven home}
Java version: 1.6.0_22, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: {java home}
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ISO-8859-1
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.18-407.el5", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[ERROR] Process did not initiate connection and is still alive; killing it
[ERROR] Failure: hudson.AbortException: Process failed to connect; exit code: 143
ERROR: Process failed to connect; exit code: 143
Sending e-mails to: {e-mail}
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: project-trunk #6 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Try non Maven Type.for your job and retry it..

Comment: Do you mean to create a "free-style software job" and not a "Maven 2/3 project"? Is there a way to know which one I'm using in each job? And can I change it after creation? Because I have some +50 jobs. :(

Comment: Same problem with the "free style job", it keeps failing around 5% of my jobs. I guess I'll have to drop Maven integration altogether and call mvn from the regular shell option.

Comment: Already reported as a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422367

Comment: Dropped Hudson for Jenkins. Maven plug-in works fine, no sign of random failures so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since having random failures defeats the whole purpose of having a continuous integration tool, the answer is moving on to Jenkins for better Maven support.